# Positioning a View at 1/3rd of the screen

Tags: android

I want to position a View so that its center is exactly at 1/3rd of the screen of any device.

I was looking at using a horizontal layout but what should I used to full the other 2/3rd of the screen?

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to set the view's weight 1/3 of its parent's weight, and just like you said, have another view to fill the rest of the space.

You can do it by setting the parent's weight with the value 3 (for example), and set 1 to the view you want and 2 for the rest. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <view
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_restofcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```